# Progress bar with rounded corners?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I am trying to achieve this progress bar design:
[image]

The current code that I have produces this:
[image]

This is the code:

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/dirtyWhite"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

My progress bar:

```
 <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/activeProgress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:progress="10"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/rounded_corners_progress_bar"/>
```

I tried adding `<size>` attribute on the `<shape>` in `<clip` to make the progress shape a bit smaller but it did not work. Also, the progress bar is flat and I want to be curved as per design. What I need to change in order to achieve the design?

Comment: https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar

Answer (score 217, accepted):

**How to make the progress shape a bit smaller?**

You need to give the progress item a little padding, like so:

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:top="2dp"
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="2dp"
    android:right="2dp">
```

**How to make the progress bar to be curved as per design?**

Replace the `<clip></clip>` element, with `<scale android:scaleWidth="100%"></scale>`. That will make the shape keep its form as it grows - and not cut off.
Unfortunately, it will have a little unwanted visual effect at the beginning - as the shape corners don't have enough space to draw. But it might be good enough for most cases.

**Full code:**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/dirtyWhite"/>
    </shape>
 </item>

 <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:top="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp">

    <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        </shape>
    </scale>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, when I applied your suggestions. the whole progress bar got coloured with my main color (colorPrimaryDark) although the progress attribute as set to 10% No idea why this happened. I edited my answer with the progress bar code as well.

Comment: Thanks! It achieves the progress bar curve effect. However, when I apply your suggestions the whole progress bar gets filled up as it it is set to 100% progress. Do you know what is causing this? Thanks!

Comment: Please its does not work properly with gradient progress, when we set 100 % width , it round both ends of progress but it also wrapup the gradient, but i want show graidient according to progress value. if you have any solution pleas share

Comment: How can we remove the unwanted visual effect - flat progress at the beginning when the progress is very small ?? @EyalBiran

Comment: @habibullah Using the native ProgressBar and Layer-List is very restricting. You can easily implement a custom progress bar to fit your needs. For example, if you have a solid color background - simply use a foreground 9-path to hide everything but the progress. If you are targeting newer Android Versions you can simply use the built in mask support (not supported in older versions). Another option is to use a library, this might be good for you: https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar . If you are still having problems, please post a new question. Cheers.

Comment: @AkshayMahajan see comment above

Comment: When I applied your full code, the whole progress bar got coloured with my main color (colorPrimaryDark) although the progressis not 100%. I added clip tag under @android:id/background, it fixed, but background has gone. My temp solution is removing background item and adding background color to layout (without rounded corners).

Comment: @EyalBiran hello, thank your for the answer, its working, but i didn't see the progress when i try to execute the progress bar from 100 to 0, i ever try adding one more item with id secondaryProgress, but it doesn't work, did you have any solution? please share, thank you

Comment: In my case, the `scale` with `android:scaleWidth="100%"` did the trick in order to display it with rounded corners. Many thanks

Comment: `scale` instead of `clip` mainly does the trick. Then rest is your customization whether you want the rounded corners on both sides or only a single side. :)  Thanks @EyalBiran for the answer.

Answer (score 60):

With the Material Components Library you can use the **`LinearProgressIndicator`** and the **`app:trackCornerRadius`** attribute.
Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
        android:indeterminate="true"
        app:trackThickness="xxdp"
        app:trackCornerRadius="xdp"/>
```

[image]

It works also for the determinate progress indicator removing the `android:indeterminate="true"` or using `android:indeterminate="false"`

**Note:** it requires at least the version **`1.3.0`**.

Comment: @Arunachalamk  LinearProgressIndicator [was introduced](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.3.0-alpha04/lib/java/com/google/android/material/progressindicator/LinearProgressIndicator.java) with the **1.3.0-alpha04**, currently the latest alpha version.

Comment: I was trying to achieve the same effect on a circular progress view and this helped me. trackCornerRadius exists for that as well. Docs on both linear and circular progress indicators available here https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/ProgressIndicator.md

Comment: Can we add rounded border to LinearProgressIndicator when indeterminate="false"?

Comment: @nilesh Currently there isn't a parameter to add a stroke.

Comment: It is really hard to have indeterminate rounded horizontal animation (like the native one) if you don't know about this view. THANKS!!!!!

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to Georgi Koemdzhiev for a nice question and images. For those who want to make similar to his, do the following.

1) Create a background for a `ProgressBar`.

progress_bar_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <stroke android:color="@color/white" android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```

2) Create a scale for the `ProgressBar`.

curved_progress_bar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="2dp" />
                <solid android:color="#ffff00" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

3) In layout file add the `ProgressBar`.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/progress_bar_background"
    >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/curved_progress_bar"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: android:indeterminate="false"

this line saved my day :)

Comment: Still valid in 2022, nice one!

Answer (score 6):

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
                android:id="@+id/pb_team2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                app:trackColor="#E0E0E0"
                app:trackCornerRadius="6dp"
                app:trackThickness="8dp"
                android:progress="2"
                app:indicatorColor="@color/red"
                android:scaleX="-1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_versus"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_team2_score" />
```

Answer (score 5):

[image: The code produce following progress bar]
    You can achieve progress bar with both inner progress color ,border 
    color,empty progress with transparent color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="15dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/black"
                android:centerColor="@color/trans"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="@color/black"
                android:angle="270"

                />
        </shape>
    </clip>
 </item>


 <item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    >
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/black"
                android:endColor="@color/black"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
 </item>
 </layer-list>
```

Comment: Hi Ravichandra, thanks for your answer! Can you add explanation why your code answers his question? Otherwise, it'll be difficult to use for other users. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made. Furthermore, try to explain why your answer is better than the other answers already given to this question.

Answer (score 2):

add material dependencies in **build.gradle(Module)**
implementation `'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'`

come back at **activity_main.xml**. Add

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator>
...
 app:trackCornerRadius="3dp"
    </com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator>
```

Hope it will do your work.

Answer (score 2):

### You can create a custom `progressbar` with Drawable.

###### 1) create first drawable as a `custom_progress_bar_horizontal.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dip"
                android:left="2dip"
                android:right="2dip"
                android:top="2dip" />
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#80385682"
                android:centerY="0.50"
                android:endColor="#80577AAF"
                android:startColor="#80222F44" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:angle="90"
                    android:endColor="#FF1997E1"
                    android:startColor="#FF0E75AF" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

###### 2) Create style in `style.xml` file.

```
<style name="CustomProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
   <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
   <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progress_bar_horizontal</item>
   <item name="android:minHeight">10dip</item>
   <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
</style>
```

###### 3) Use anywhere in your project.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/mProgressBar"
    style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

### Output:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new style

```
<style name="ProgressBar.Horizontal.Rounded" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_material</item>
</style>
```

2. Create a new drawable called "progress_horizontal.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <size android:height="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white_disabled" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"
                android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated">
                <corners android:radius="8dp" />
                <size android:height="4dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/white_disabled" />
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"
                android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated">
                <corners android:radius="8dp" />
                <size android:height="4dp" />
                <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

3. Create a new color called "white_disabled.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Copyright (C) 2015 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="?android:attr/disabledAlpha" android:color="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

4. Use it then in your layout like this:

```
<ProgressBar
     android:id="@+id/progress_bar_indicator"
     style="@style/ProgressBar.Horizontal.Rounded"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```