# ProgressBar custom layout corners not working

Tags: android, layout, progress-bar, customization

I'm trying to create a custom progressBar in my Android app, but I'm stuck in applying the corners on the progress layout.

Here is the intended result:
[image]

My code is this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:gravity="center">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
                android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="#026B91" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

And the layout result from the code:
[image]

I can't seem to do the round corner from the progress layout, I tried different approaches but nothing works. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: remove padding 1dp.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I doesn't affect it, plus I need that padding for the intended design.

Comment: @Phantom remove left and right padding for corners.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper I tried that, but no changes in the final result.

Comment: Strange the I just copy and paste your code and remove that padding and it is working for me.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Can you copy your code in a pastebin and paste the link here?

Comment: @Phantom see my answer this is what I do and the output is the screenshot.

Comment: @Phantom may be you are setting background instead of progressDrawable in progressbar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154985/discussion-between-andy-developer-and-phantom).

Comment: Have you seen this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646574/progress-bar-with-rounded-corners

Comment: @Merian Thank you so much, that was exactly the answer I was looking for. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Use below drawable as your progressbar drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
<shape>
    <solid
            android:color="@color/progbar_color" />
    <corners android:radius="60dp"/>
</shape>
</item>

<item
android:id="@android:id/progress">
<clip>
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="@color/progbar_track_color" />
        <corners android:radius="60dp"/>
    </shape>
</clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: @pskink Thanks, but then do you know another approach on how can I achieve my design?

Comment: @pskink Thanks, I tried the <scale> one but it doesn't work. Thanks for the other answer also, but I'm trying to do this via XML. I'm still searching for a solution for that.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:gravity="center">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
                android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="#026B91" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

My experience is that if you want to set `android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"` and `android:topRightRadius="20dp"` you should set **android:radius="0dp"** also.

Comment: Thanks, but still the same result.