# How to make oval shape of progress in horizontal progress-bar in android

Tags: android

This background drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />
            <solid android:color="#cccccc" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"

        >
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="12dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Below is my progress-bar

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/point_default_progess"
        android:progress="2"
        android:scaleY="0.80" />
```

I want to set  progress shape inside progress-bar with oval shape but i am unable to set oval shape. please suggest me how to fix this issue below is my screen .

[image]

I want to make progress view in oval shape please help me in this issue.

Expected image is below

[image]

i want to set oval shape below 3 progress value .

Comment: Just Remove `style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"` from your `ProgressBar`

Comment: no i want progress status in horizontal progress view as oval @NileshRathod

Comment: can u share your expected output as image

Comment: @NileshRathod please check in question i have attached expected screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress bar with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646574/progress-bar-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: @VishvaDave i tried same but not working as my expected i want to set oval shape progress for below value 2

Answer (score 2):

background_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#777" />
        <size
            android:width="15dp"
            android:height="15dp" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <color android:color="#00000000" />
            </item>
            <item
                android:left="2dp"
                android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:bottom="2dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#068310" />
                    <size
                        android:width="15dp"
                        android:height="15dp" />
                    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
                </shape>
              </item>
           </layer-list>
        </clip>
     </item>
  </layer-list>
```

progress-bar.xml

```
   <ProgressBar
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/background_drawable" />
```

hope it helps.

Comment: this also coming as rectangle simple i want for value 2 progress view as oval save within progressbar @Amrnoid

Answer (score 0):

just replace `<clip>` with `<scale>`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="12dp" />
        <solid android:color="#cccccc" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
        </shape>
    </scale>
</item>
```

Comment: then there will problem for value 1 and 2, and 3 it progress view will come out side progress bar @V-rund Puro-hit

Comment: than i suggest you use [this](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar) library because it can't be done with `clip`