# How to create horizontal indeterminate progress drawable with round corners for progressbar in android?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to create horizontal indeterminate progress drawable with round corners for progress bar in android. How to create that using xml?

**Edit 1:** I am using following drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="?attr/dividerAndProgressColor" />
        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="?attr/secondaryText" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    >
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="?attr/secondaryText" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>


android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable_start_end_indeterminate"
```

But there is one problem, animation starts from 0 reaches 100 and then restarts. This is not desired in case of indeterminate progressbar.

Answer (score 1):

round corner
lookout this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42646939/12709358

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateOnly="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_horizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_horizontal"
    android:minHeight="24dip"
    android:maxHeight="24dip" 
   />
```

also see this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63463786/12709358

Comment: I want round corners.

Comment: There is one problem when I set custom indeterminate drawable to progressbar then, it starts from 0, reaches 100 and the restarts again. But it does not makes beginning space empty when it reaches to end i.e. 100.

Comment: Yes, I posted that drawable code, see edit 1.